# entity manager not persisting in database

Tags: java, spring, transactions, persistence, entitymanager

I made a form with jpa sending a client (checked values to the service which in turn call the dao to persist the client in db, the process completes without exception but the client is not persisted using the entity manager

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/enregistrer")
    public String enregistrerClient(Model model, Client client){
        if(client == null){
            System.out.println("client is null");
        }else{
            System.out.println("name : "+client.getNom()+" prenom "+client.getPrenom());
            client = clientService.save(client);
        }

        return "redirect:/clients/";
    }
```

the service (all methods are transactionnal)

```
public Client save(Client entity) {
        //entity.setIdClient(4);
        Client c = dao.save(entity);
        System.out.println("saved element "+c.getNom());
        return c;
    }
```

and the dao

```
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

@Override
    public E save(E entity) {
        try{
            em.persist(entity);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

which is not printing any exception

here is my application context

```
    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_stock_mvc?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>  
    </bean>

    <bean name="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property> 
    </bean>

    <bean name="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_GESTION_DE_STOCK_MVC"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="stock.mvc" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
```

and my persistence unit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="UP_GESTION_DE_STOCK_MVC"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Are you able to update any data? Is there an issue with (auto-)commit? Could you show more of your transaction setup (eg. where is the @Transactional method? Does it maybe have readOnly=true?)

Comment: I annotated the service with 
@ Service (extra space to avoid referring stackoverflow users)
@ Transactional
public class ClientServiceImpl implements IClientService {

Comment: Do you see any INSERT or UPDATE in the logs?

Comment: @Simon there no insert or update in the logs

Comment: when trying to force the commit using    em.persist(entity);
   em.getTransaction().commit(); I get the following exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:198)

Comment: Could you show us the code/configuration for the data source, transactionManager, entityManagerFactory etc. (whatever you have customized)?

Comment: @Simon I updated the description with the xml configuration and the dao annotation

Comment: Fixed by adding  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <context:annotation-config ></context:annotation-config>

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding the following configuration

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
<context:annotation-config ></context:annotation-config>
```